# Given a fixed graph configuration, how to draw a cursive cluster of nodes?

Tags: graphviz

I have a nice graph, produced by fdp:

[image]

I want to draw a cluster consisting node 12, 13, 14 like this:

[image]

But introducing subgraph into the code mess the whole configuration up:

[image]

Is there a way to fix initial configuration, then simply draw a cursive cluster of the nodes?

Here is the code:

```
graph G {
    overlap=scale;
    splines = curved;
    sep="+13";
    node[penwidth=3.5 , width=1, height=1]
    edge[penwidth=2]

    subgraph clusterA{
    14
    13
    12
    }

    2 -- 5
    2 -- 6
    3 -- 6
    3 -- 7
    3 -- 8
    4 -- 5
    4 -- 2
    4 -- 11
    5 -- 6
    5 -- 9
    6 -- 8
    6 -- 9
    6 -- 10
    6 -- 12
    7 -- 8
    8 -- 10
    9 -- 11
    10 -- 12
    10 -- 13
    12 -- 13
    13 -- 14
    14 -- 10
    14 -- 8
    15 -- 2
    15 -- 3

    6[color="dodgerblue4"];
    5[color="dodgerblue4"];
    8[color="dodgerblue4"];
    10[color="dodgerblue4"];
}
```

Comment: What does cursive mean in this context?

Comment: @sroush I added an example in the post. Can you check it

Comment: How do you want your final result to differ from the dotted-line image - repeatability, straight lines, positioning of the 3 nodes, ...?  (p.s. I thought you could do this with pin attribute, but not so much) (p.p.s. oddly, my version is a left-right swapped version of yours - mostly)

Comment: @sroush what do you mean by repeatability? Straight line is fine. Repositioning is also fine, just don't be so messed up